# asp repeater vb.net <img>

Tags: asp.net, image, repeater

What I have is an asp repeater which brings through information for events that are created on the admin section of the web page. 
These events are allowed to have images added onto them, I am able to bring the image through correctly, but what I am attempting to do is to bring through a generic image if no image is available. 
What I have just now is:

```
    <img id="eventlogoholder"  visible="<%#If(Eval("event_logo").ToString > "", "True", "False")%>", title= "<%# Eval("event_title").ToString%>" alt="" src="<%# Replace(Eval("event_logo").ToString, Application("IMAGEFOLDER"), Application("IMAGETHUMBNAILS"))%>" />
```

So what this does is set the visible to false if no image is present else it will bring through the image.
So how could I modify the source so that it changes to:

"/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg"

if no image is present?

thanks

Scott

Comment: try to use `If` under `src` just like You do for `visible`

Comment: Yeah I tried something on the src but couldn't quiet get my head around it, what I had was:

    <img id="eventlogoholder"  visible="<%#If(Eval("event_logo").ToString > "", "True", "False")%>", title= "<%# Eval("event_title").ToString%>" alt="" src="<%#If(Eval("event_logo").ToString > "", Replace(Eval("event_logo").ToString, Application("IMAGEFOLDER"), Application("IMAGETHUMBNAILS")) Else (Eval("event_logo").ToString = "/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg"))%>"

Comment: Instead that `Else` replace it with `,` (period) ... `If(condition, do if true, do if false)`

Comment: `src='<%#If(Eval("event_logo").ToString <> "", Replace(Eval("event_logo").ToString, Application("IMAGEFOLDER"), Application("IMAGETHUMBNAILS")) , "/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg")%>'` ... since You use `eval` You have to put all code inside `'` instead `"` ... `src='**code**'` ... and, You have to use `<>` instead `>`, you dealing with string, not numbers.

Comment: of course, remove complete code block for `visible`... update: add `Trim()` for `If` condition, `Eval("event_logo").ToString.Trim` ... there can be empty, space char and condition will be True.

Comment: Thank you ever so much with your help Ivan! Would have struggled to solve this if it wasn't for you. 
So thank you once again :)
Could you post your solution as the answer and ill mark it?

Comment: I would highly recommend performing this kind of logic in the code behind. If you have to be lazy then use a ?? or a ternary operator. Something like <%#Eval(image) ?? default.jpg%> or <%#Eval(image) == string.Empty ? default.jpg :  Eval(image) %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, on of them, solution based on comments:

Instead that `Else` replace it with `,` (period) ... `If(condition, do if true, do if false)`

`src='<%#If(Eval("event_logo").ToString.Trim <> "", Replace(Eval("event_logo").ToString, Application("IMAGEFOLDER"), Application("IMAGETHUMBNAILS")) , "/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg‌​")%>'`

since You use eval You have to put all code inside `'` instead `"`,  `src='**code**'`

You have to use `<>` instead `>`, you dealing with string, not numbers.

I add `Trim` in `Eval("event_logo").ToString.Trim` ... there can be empty, space char and condition will be True

Of course, now You can remove complete code block for `visible`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using a regular HTML `<img` tag, not an `<asp:Image`. Setting `visible=false` in a regular image won't do a thing.

Either use a asp.net image or set the visibility another way like with a class (`class="hiddenImage"`) or inline CSS (`style="display: none"`).

Second your IF statement is wrong. It should look something like this `<%# Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("event_logo").ToString) %>`.

But it's better to use an asp.net image, you have more control that way.

`<asp:Image ID="eventlogoholder" runat="server" Visible='<%# Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("event_logo").ToString) %>' ImageUrl='<%# Replace(Eval("event_logo").ToString, Application("IMAGEFOLDER"), Application("IMAGETHUMBNAILS")) %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("event_title").ToString %>' AlternateText="myAltText" />`

> Note that when using a value from the Repeater you use a single quote
>   and when it's a normal attribute you use double quote.

PS translated the code from C# to VB with http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator, so it may not be 100% correct.

**UPDATE**

`ImageUrl='<%# IIf ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("event_logo").ToString), "/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg", Eval("event_logo").ToString) %>'`

or

`src="<%# IIf ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("event_logo").ToString), "/Images/Thumbnailimages/posters/Noimage.jpg", Eval("event_logo").ToString) %>"`

Comment: read again last part of question... he want to show some image that represent "that there is no picture", not how to hide... he know how to hide it if there is no image... and, why using server control for that and increase viewstate for nothing?

Comment: Because OP is talking about visibility. But updated my example so the last part of the question is answered.

Comment: Yes, You're right, he talking about visibility, but not asking. updated part of your answer is solution.